# Replace re.DOTALL with equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, coding-style

Is there any expression that can replace the flag `re.DOTALL` in the following line of python code:

```
r = re.compile(r'<p>.*<p>.', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

like add any expression to this regular expression: `r'<p>.*<p>.'` to be something like :

```
r = re.compile(r'<p>something.*<p>.', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE )
```

but need to keep the same behavior, which is matching multiline string (paragraph)

Thanks

Comment: Note you seem to be trying to extract content from HTML using regular expressions, in which case [have you considered an HTML parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it backwards, and the following two should be equivalent:

```
r = re.compile(r'<p>[\s\S]*<p>.', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

r = re.compile(r'<p>.*<p>.', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

That is, matching `.*` in `DOTALL` mode should behave the same as matching `[\s\S]*` with `DOTALL` mode disabled.

Comment: I am providing the regular expression from a json input file to the script like this: "regex":"<p>[\s\S]*<p>"  but still showing an error message "Error decoding json in file "input_file.json" "

Comment: JSON?  Don't use regex on JSON, use a parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [inline flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) `(?s)`.

```
re.compile(regex, re.DOTALL)
```

is equivalent to

```
re.compile('(?s)' + regex)
```